# Paint canvas not working properly

Tags: javascript, canvas

http://www.asifslab.com/reveal.js-master/Why%20does%20wind%20feel%20cold.html#/4
Why doesn't the drawing canvas work properly? The line drawn is away from the point clicked. However, if I use the canvas out of reveal.js it works perfectly. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEaKh
Also when the erase function is run, it leaves a white border outside. How do I fix these problems?

Comment: The first link is dead. Please update it and add the relevant source code here.

Answer (score 0):

just change `e.pageX` to `e.clientX` and `e.pageY` to `e.clientY` because in your codepen account
canvas origin and page origin is almost at same place but in other it is not.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the mouse position you need to subtract the position of the canvas:

Here is one way of doing this (inside the event handler):

```
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = e.clientX - rect.left,
    y = e.clientY - rect.top;
```

Now your `x` and `y` will be relative to canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a copy/pasta of a small part of my paint app.  Notice I'm using offsets of the canvas in my calculations.  I also have a zoom function that scales the canvas, so taking into account that I added it to the calculation of the mouse cursor.

```
$('canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    // x and y are globals, x inits to null, mousedown sets x, mouseup returns x to null
    if (x==null) return;
    x = (100/$('#zoom').val())*(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
    y = (100/$('#zoom').val())*(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);

    $('#debug').html(x+', '+y); // constantly update (x,y) position in a fixed div during debugging
});
```